# ListView inside fragment recreating after adding item

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm picking images from my phone's gallery to my fragmentA's listview. Form activity holds my fragmentA. Now the problem is, "sometimes" after I already put some image uri on the listview, and adding another one, previous image uri's disappears. But sometimes previous uri's stays after adding another one. Is it a bug or something?

```
ListView lv;
ArrayList<Uri> array_list = new ArrayList<Uri>();
ArrayAdapter<Uri> array_adapter;

final int RQS_LOADIMAGE = 0;

onCreate .... {

array_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Uri>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);
        lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list_ai);
        lv.setAdapter(array_adapter);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) 
        {
            case R.id.button_ai:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_LOADIMAGE);
            break;
        }           
    }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      if (requestCode == RQS_LOADIMAGE) {

          if(resultCode == Form.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            array_list.add(imageUri);
            array_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
          }
      }
    }
```